Only get part of the SharePoint list with JavaScript Fetch
I have a problem with getting all SP list item (257 currently) with fetch.
I have the following code:
var tasks = new Request(
        webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items?$top=300"
    , {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: 'same-origin',    
        headers: new Headers({
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=nometadata",
        })
    });


    fetch(tasks)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            let items = data.value;
            console.log('Van: ' + data["@odata.nextLink"])
            items.forEach((item) => {
                console.log(item.ID,item.Title,item.Program);
            });
        });

Without the top=300 part it is only listing 131 item. And it wont work with a list with 1000+ row.
The odata.nextLink is undefined. So it seems I don't get that. How can I get all data?

How many items it is returning with $top=300?

List currently has~250row. So top300 return it all.

This is the default behavior of SharePoint REST APIs. If you do not mention $top, it returns 100 items by default. So, you have to use $top to retrieve more items. You can get up to 5000 items using $top in one API call. Let me know if it helps.

If you want to get more than 5000 items, use $top=5000 and then in response, you will get nextLink property.

So if i want to be safe i should just use $top=5000? I will try tomorrow.

Yes, let me know if it works after your testing.

Thank you Ganesh.  $top=5000 working. i get all 6200 item back now.

Great, glad it worked for you.

This is the default behavior of SharePoint REST APIs:

If you do not mention $top in REST API endpoint, it returns 100 items by default.

So, you have to use $top to retrieve more than 100 items in single API call. You can get up to 5000 items using $top in one API call.
If you want to get more than 5000 items, use $top=5000 and then in response, you will get nextLink (__next) property.
Check answers given here for full code to retrieve more than 5000 items in recursive API calls:

Rest to read more than 5000 items from document library
SharePoint Online list items 5000 +, rest query

